# Load excel sheet with c#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

First i apologize for the mistakes in my text, english is not my native language and i do my best.
I'm a very beginner in coding and i have a little question about loading an excel sheet.

I'm trying to do a project with vb in c# and i have to load an excel sheet which already exist and write in it. I found some explanations who help me to create a New sheet and write in it :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Excel.Application oXL;
        Excel._Workbook oWB;
        Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
        Excel.Range oRng;

        try
        {

            oXL = new Excel.Application("Exemple.xlsx");
            oXL.Visible = true;


            oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value));
            oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;

            oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "First Name";
            oSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Last Name";
            oSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Full Name";



            oSheet.get_Range("A1", "C1").Font.Bold = true;
            oSheet.get_Range("A1", "C1").VerticalAlignment =
                Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;


            string[,] saNames = new string[5, 2];

            saNames[0, 0] = "John";
            saNames[0, 1] = "Smith";
            saNames[1, 0] = "Tom";
            saNames[1, 1] = "Brown";
            saNames[2, 0] = "Sue";
            saNames[2, 1] = "Thomas";
            saNames[3, 0] = "Jane";
            saNames[3, 1] = "Jones";
            saNames[4, 0] = "Adam";
            saNames[4, 1] = "Johnson";


            oSheet.get_Range("A2", "B6").Value2 = saNames;


            oRng = oSheet.get_Range("C2", "C6");
            oRng.Formula = "=A2 & \" \" & B2";


            oXL.Visible = true;
            oXL.UserControl = true;
        }
        catch (Exception theException)
        {
            String errorMessage;
            errorMessage = "Error: ";
            errorMessage = String.Concat(errorMessage, theException.Message);
            errorMessage = String.Concat(errorMessage, " Line: ");
            errorMessage = String.Concat(errorMessage, theException.Source);

            MessageBox.Show(errorMessage, "Error");
        }
    }
```

The things i write don't really matter but i can't load my own sheet. I tought by replacing

```
oXL = new Excel.Application();
```

by

```
oXL = new Excel.Application("Exemple.xlsx");
```

I could load my sheet ( call Exemple.xlsx)

Unfortunately it don't work, could you tell me what's wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Just a reminder; if you use interop, then Office should be installed in your target computer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your reference to Excel, you must call the [Workbooks.Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open.aspx) method to open an existing file:

```
 oXL = new Excel.Application();
 oWB = (Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Open("Example.xlsx"));
```